# ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.appengine'

Tags: python

I can't run my script I'm using python3 and I install pyrebase and his dependencies

I got this below exception when I try to run my script on linux ubuntu

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapping2fb.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pyrebase
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyrebase/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pyrebase import initialize_app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py", line 19, in <module>
    from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.appengine import is_appengine_sandbox
```

Can some one help me

Thank you

The script that i try to run

```
from urllib.request import urlopen ,URLError,HTTPError,Request
from socket import timeout
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime
import pyrebase
def is_exist_firebase_db_AR(siteName,title):#(siteName,title):
    global config
    global email
    global password
    firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
    db=firebase.database()
    auth = firebase.auth()
    user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
    all_items = db.child("items_ar").get(user['idToken'])
    if(all_items.each() is not None):
        for item in all_items.each():
            if(siteName in item.val().get("nomSite") and title in item.val().get("titre")):
               return 1
    return 0
```

Comment: Can you include your code as well?

Comment: Do you have the `requests` package installed?

Comment: yes it's installed!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the `pyrebase` package.

Since [commit 8e17600ef60de4faf632acb55d15cb3c178de9bb](https://github.com/requests/requests/commit/8e17600ef60de4faf632acb55d15cb3c178de9bb) which went into `v2.16.0`, `requests` no longer bundle `urllib3`.

The package `pyrebase` is relying on this implementation detail, and, like all things that rely on implementation details eventually do, was broken.